# Centering a UL menu of unknown width, overflow issues

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I created a simplified demo of what I'm looking to accomplish but basically, when I resize (smaller) I get scrollbars I would like to remove.

Adding overflow: hidden to the nav element works...until I want to add in sub-menus.

http://jsfiddle.net/aKUAP/

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p>Looking for a way to hide the scrollbars created when the page is resized smaller. Using overflow:hidden on the nav element will hide any sub-menus used downt he line.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;    
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;    
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    /*overflow: hidden; */
}
ul {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}
ul a {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;   
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Maybe there's a better technique for centering a UL menu of unknown items at 100% width?

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to using `overflow-x: hidden`: http://jsfiddle.net/aKUAP/2/

> Maybe there's a better technique for centering a UL menu of unknown
>   items at 100% width?

Yes, there is. Switch to using `display: inline-block` on the `ul`, and `text-align: center` on `nav`: http://jsfiddle.net/aKUAP/3/

Comment: Wow... I forgot about the x/y constrained overflows. I'll try your second method too as long as it works in the major browsers.