# Centering elements with unknown width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider the following problem: You want to center a menu, which will change it's content( For example after pressing a button, the content of the first button is to set it from "Hello" to "Greetings, user!" Or something along those lines. The important thing is that the width of the elements will be a variable.

Suppose that you also want to center the contents of your element. An approach I found is basically this:

```
 .centerMe1 {  
     margin-right: auto ;
     margin-left: auto ;
     max-width: 500px;
 }
```

This works pretty nicely, except I can't use it in this case, since I don't know the width of the element. I tried to use float:left, because it sets the width of the parent to be equal to the width of it's children, but it didn't work. Basically the width was set correctly, but the element wasn't centered.

This is the second class:

```
.centerMe2 {
     margin-right: auto ;
     float: left;
     margin-left: auto ;
}
```

And the entire source code(to make the testing easier)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Center Error</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
         <style type="text/css">
             .centerMe1 {  
                 margin-right: auto ;
                 margin-left: auto ;
                 max-width:500px;
             }
             .centerMe2 {
                 margin-right: auto ;
                 float: left;
                 margin-left: auto ;
             }
         </style>
   </head>

  <body>
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span12">
             <ul class="nav nav-pills centerMe1">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">adsadw er sdfw</a> </li>
                 <li><a href="#">QQQQQQQQQQQQQ</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">some other random gibberish</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.centerMe1` will work just fine if you remove the `max-width` attribute. `float` wont work

Comment: Would a js solution be out of scope for you ?

Comment: I think you need to add the "text-center" css class to its container also. And btw, giving a div the "span12" class is quite redundant. You can just delete this div.

Comment: #x4rf41 you are correct. Please post it  as an answer, so I can accept it when the thread timer expires.

Comment: maybe you want to take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779258/centering-a-ul-menu-of-unknown-width-overflow-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `ul` a block element, so it will take up the full width, you can set the `li` to `display:inline-block`. Now that the `li` item's are inline block they can be centered with `text-align:center;`

```
ul {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CZ9pX/1/

Answer (score 0):

> you just have to give

```
 text-align:center;
```

to the outer container,dont use float. use `display:block`.

```
div{ text-align:center;display:block}
div span{font-size:12px;}
```

This will make span appear in the middle.